# script function will not open modal

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input type="CheckBox" with an onclick function to launch a modal if the checkbox is clicked.  But it will not launch the modal?
I inserted an alert(id); under the if statement & it did alert "chkfb", so I know the result is "TRUE", but the $('#Searchfb').modal(); will not work.

Added the scripts at the bottom of

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en" dir="ltr">

 <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
       shrink-to-fit=no">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

 <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">

 <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"> 

<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
<script    
src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function myCheckBoxFunction(id) {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById(id);
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
      $('#SearchFb').modal();
    } else {}
  }
</script>

<input id="chkFb" type="checkbox" onclick="myCheckBoxFunction(this.id);" /> 
  <label for="chkFb">&nbspFb Services</label>


<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="Searchfb" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data- dismiss="modal">&times; 
                      </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
          dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
   integrity="sha384- 
   q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script 
   src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/
   umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
   UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" 
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script 
   src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/
   js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
   JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" 
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery and jQuery UI? Have you checked your browser's console for errors?

Comment: $('#SearchFb').modal('show'); is the correct syntax

Comment: Looks like you are just initializing it, not telling it to open

Comment: J08691, I did an inspect element & it does show an error:  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: j08691,  I checked the console for errors & you were right, I have the following error:   "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function"  I thought that I had included the jQuery UI, but I will check that also.

Comment: I have the following in the <head> :  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>   is this not correct?

Comment: I have the current version of .css and jQuery UI is included. I am still getting this one error:   Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function.

Comment: Just a note, I have several other jQuery script that works with no problems.  It seems that what ever is causing this has to do with the modal call  $('#SearchFb').modal('show');.

Comment: Hello Jay, I happened to see the question that you posted here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/329556/uncaught-typeerror-modal-is-not-a-function and I noticed that you are not including bootstrap anywhere in your html. `$(...).modal()` is a bootstrap function so you need to include the bootstrap css and js files via `<script>` and `<link>`.

Comment: Kodos, Thank you for commenting.  I added to the above & still getting errors.  I have these in the <head> area of my code.   Do I not have the correct versions of bootstrap?

Answer (score 1):

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modalshow

```
$('#Searchfb').modal('show');
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you id name

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="Searchfb" role="dialog">
```

Remember, the id name must be the same in you script

```
    $('#SearchFb').modal('show');
```

So just need change for fb or Fb in the html or the js code. Happy code!

Comment: I did correct that - thanks, but i'm getting the following error:  Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

Comment: You need add jquery in you code. Check this here: https://jsfiddle.net/y7qgrxa2/3/